# Joukowski Transformation and Unit Circles

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show algebraically that the Joukowski transformation maps the unit circle, $|z| = 1$, to the straight line segment, $-2 \le u \le 2$ and $v = 0$.

Other information given is that $u+iv = f(x+iy)$ where $u=u(x,y)$ and $v=v(x,y)$.

For example if $w = z^2$, then $u+iv = (x+iy)^2 = x^2-y^2+2ixy$ and the transformation is $u=x^2 - y^2, v= 2xy$.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant $-2 \le u \le 2$ ***not*** $-2 \le u \ge 2$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yes. Sorry I am not used to the formatting and it was a silly error.

Comment: You should accept an answer if you are satisfied or ask a further question if you are still confused.

Answer (score 0):

In $Z=J(z)=(z+\frac{1}{z})$, plug $z=e^{it}$, you then get $Z=2 cos(t)$ which takes its values into line segment $[-2,2]$ (no imaginary part).

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved rather easily because we know the set $|z|=1=e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta \epsilon [0,2\pi)$. Thus, $J(z)=e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}$. We then see that this can rewritten as:

- $J(z)=[\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)]+[\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta)]$
  $    =2\cos(\theta)$

We then know that $\cos(\theta)$ for $\theta \epsilon [0,2\pi)$ takes on the values [-1,1]. Thus multiplying this by 2 gives us the image of a straight line from [-2,2].